# Email not Sent Using Shell cmd/script on Centos

Tags: email, centos, smtp, sh, postfix-mta

I'm trying to send an email from my centos using shell cmd to my gmail address.

Here is configuration that I have done:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
myhostname = relay.example.com
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd**

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 My_Address@gmail.com:My_Password
```

**I created hash db file for Postfix:**

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

**I run the cmd after restarting Postfix:**

```
echo "Body" | mail -s "Subject" My_Address@gmail.com
```

**I set gmail so that it can accept less secure apps.**

**Note that I don't have networking problems issues (as you see the connectivity below):**

[1st Connectivity Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11OJS.png)
[2nd Connectivity Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvDdk.png)

After running the cmd no error appears, but the message is not sent.

**Veiw of logs: tail -f /var/log/maillog**

```
Nov  2 00:55:43 quickstart sendmail[5228]: wA1JwGn3031205: to=<My_Address@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<cloudera@quickstart.cloudera> (501/501), delay=11:56:47, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=390482, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Nov  2 00:55:43 quickstart sendmail[5228]: wA1JchlC026214: to=<My_Address@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<cloudera@quickstart.cloudera> (501/501), delay=12:16:44, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=480482, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Nov  2 00:55:43 quickstart sendmail[5228]: wA1JCSq5019689: to=<My_Address@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<cloudera@quickstart.cloudera> (501/501), delay=12:42:59, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=480482, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Nov  2 01:17:17 quickstart postfix/postfix-script[8412]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
Nov  2 01:17:17 quickstart postfix/postfix-script[8469]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./main.cf
Nov  2 01:17:17 quickstart postfix/postfix-script[8483]: starting the Postfix mail system
Nov  2 01:17:17 quickstart postfix/master[8484]: fatal: bind 127.0.0.1 port 25: Address already in use
Nov  2 01:18:14 quickstart sendmail[8554]: wA28IEGk008554: from=cloudera, size=228, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201811020818.wA28IEGk008554@quickstart.cloudera>, relay=root@localhost
Nov  2 01:18:14 quickstart sendmail[8558]: wA28IEsc008558: from=<cloudera@quickstart.cloudera>, size=483, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201811020818.wA28IEGk008554@quickstart.cloudera>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov  2 01:18:14 quickstart sendmail[8554]: wA28IEGk008554: to=My_Addressq@gmail.com, ctladdr=cloudera (501/501), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30228, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (wA28IEsc008558 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Could you please help, thanks!

Comment: Please post your postfix logs that show the errors.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I just've added a veiw of Maillog. If it's what you asked for ?

Comment: Google won't accept where the from address is localhost, you're postfix server isn't attaching a real domain to the user.

Comment: Can you please re-check the (new) view of Maillog that I just put. (the previous wasn't the one concerned). My bad!

Comment: Postfix isn't running because something else is running on port 25. Run `lsof | egrep -i "25|SMTP"` This should tell you what's sitting on port 25. Probably sendmail. However the last line indicates that google accepted the message from sendmail.

Comment: Actually I did run some email workflows on port 25 using Oozie (they didn't work also). I stopped Cloudera Manager (Oozie included), and I tried to re-send the message, here are the actual Maillog [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glu6v.png).
If you want more details about my oozie workflows you can refer to [Email not Sent Using Oozie (Job Succeeded!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108152/email-not-sent-using-oozie-job-succeeded). 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **Sendmail** also was installed, which is another mail server. So automatically **Postfix** was disabled because there can't be two of them running at the same time.

**Here is the fatal error from logs: tail -f /var/log/maillog**

```
Nov  2 01:17:17 quickstart postfix/postfix-script[8412]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

**I resoleved it by removing sendmail completely**

```
[root@quickstart ~]# yum remove sendmail
```

**Then restarting Postfix**

```
[root@quickstart ~]# service postfix restart
Shutting down postfix:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting postfix:                                          [  OK  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you don't have problem with network. There is small change needed in the mail sending script. Please follow the below format and let me if it works

```
echo "Body" | mail -s "Subject" -m My_Address@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity, it's already working. I put some details in my answer.